# Search and Append with new line Linux

Tags: regex, awk, replace, sed, find

```
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }
```

I would like to add @Before for every method in all classes. I have nearly 500+ classes. If I do manually it will be very tough.

```
        @Before
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }
```

I have tried this

```
sed -i "s/protected void setUp()/@Before()\nprotected void setUp()/g" File
```

But If I do this alignment changed.

```
    @Before()
protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {

    }
```

Please help me . I would like to have proper alignment

Comment: what is the constant part? `protected void`?

Comment: protected void setUp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong in `sed` with that simple task:

```
sed -r -i -e "s/^([ \t]*)(protected void setUp())/\1@Before()\n\1\2/g" File
```

- Remember to add `-r` parameter to activate regex syntax in `sed`,
- Use `^([ \t]*)' to get indent,
- Apply indent before inserted decorator, and also before original line.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk you can use [`gensub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to capture the number of spaces in front of `protected void setUp()` and print them in front of the desired text:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/^(\s*)(protected void setUp)/, "\\1@Before\n&", 1)}1' file
        @Before
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {
              //...
        }
```

See how this works:

- `$0=gensub()`
  perform the changes and set the current record to this value.
- `gensub(/^(\s*)(protected void setUp)/, "\\1@Before\n&", 1)`
  this looks for the string `protected void setUp` with some spaces in the beginning and captures both. Then, it replaces it with those spaces + "@Before", followed by a new line and the original line.
- `1`
  it triggers the awk's default action, consistent in printing the current (updated) line.

Note this just checks up to `protected void setUp`. If you also want to check the parentheses after `setUp`, say: `/^(\s*)(protected void setUp\(\))/` (escaping the parentheses is required, since normal ones have the function of capturing groups).

This takes into account that captured groups can be used by saying `\\n`, being `n` its ordinal, or `&` for the full string.

---

See it in action with more extreme sample file:

```
 $ cat a
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }

blablablabla
 protected void setUp() throws Exception

and this is
               protected void setUp() throws Exception
```

It becomes:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/^(\s*)(protected void setUp)/, "\\1@Before\n&", 1)}1' a
        @Before
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }

blablablabla
 @Before
 protected void setUp() throws Exception

and this is
               @Before
               protected void setUp() throws Exception
```

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. That's not what you are trying to do so it's not a job for sed, it's a job for awk. This will work in any awk:

```
$ awk '{s=$0} sub(/protected void setUp().*/,"@Before",s){print s} 1' file
        @Before
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }
```

Borrowing @fedorqui's more comprehensive sample input file:

```
$ cat a
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }

blablablabla
 protected void setUp() throws Exception

and this is
               protected void setUp() throws Exception

$ awk '{s=$0} sub(/protected void setUp().*/,"@Before",s){print s} 1' a
        @Before
        protected void setUp() throws Exception
        {

              //...
        }

blablablabla
 @Before
 protected void setUp() throws Exception

and this is
               @Before
               protected void setUp() throws Exception
```